# Visual estudio no reconoce referencias inmediatamente

Tags: visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2017

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de levantar un ambiente en visual studio 2017, el proyect fué desarrollado vs 2008, sin embargo yo he levantado ambientes hasta de 1.0, pero esta solució tiene 51 proyectos, esa es la unica variante, el comportamiento es el siguiente:

1: El intelisence no reconoce las referencias por lo que marca error y no se pude hace build.
2: Si entras a la clase donde está el error, intelisence lo detecta y quita el error.

3: Si hago todo eso, y quito lo errores al intentar hacer build, lo errres vuelven a  aparacer.

Imagenes:
1[image: Entro dando doble clic]
2[image: Error marcado]

3[image: Y el error se arregla mágicamente]

Podrían ayudarme por favor, urge!

Comment: Bienvenido de preferencia que tu codigo se en texto no una imagen es mas facil leerlo

Comment: Pues el problema no es el código sino el comportamiento de visual studio, el cual no puede ser descrito por medio de código. Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a ir a Herramientas/opciones/Proyectos y soluciones/General y desactiva "Permitir inicializacion paralela de proyectos". Cierra la solucion y vuelve a abrirla

Comment: Si ya probé, y sigue igual

Comment: ¿Creen que deba forzosamene abrirlo en vs2008?

Comment: No tendrías porque. Prueba tambien a borrar todos los archivos .suo a ver si así...Estos problemas suelen ser dificiles de resolver de todas maneras, suerte.

Comment: hol gracias! ja ja ja tiene el mismo comportamiento con vs2008 pero bueno  intentaré. Thansk.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo vayas compilando proyecto a proyecto. Desde la "capa" más interna a la más "externa". Es decir, ve compilando según las referencias. Puede que el orden de compilación de los diferentes proyectos no esté del todo bien configurado. Revisa también que las referencias entre proyectos NO sea vía `dll`compilada.

Comment: Hola a todos, lo que hice fué irme a VS2008, y compilar ahí. S´lo que si hay un error debo restaruar y recopiar las DLL's, y reacer las referencias.

Saludos